# IdMappedPortTCP OnOutboundConnect SSL support

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I'm trying to create a simple program that allows non-SSL aware clients to communicate through SSL.

Basically, IdMappedPortTCP accepts non-encrypted (not SSL) from clients and forwards the data through SSL to the specified MappedHost and MappedPort properties.

So far I tried the following code on the OnOutboundConnect event but it seems not working:

```
AContext.Connection.IOHandler :=  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(AContext.Connection);
```

Think of it as a simple version of **stunnel** (SSL/TLS proxy)

Comment: When I said "not working", I meant that the IOHandler is ignored and even the program does not complain about missing OpenSSL DLLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the wrong IOHandler in the wrong event.

You are assigning the IOHandler of the connection to the client, not the IOHandler of the connection to the mapped server.  And you are doing so in the event that is fired after the connection to the mapped server has been established.

Also, when establishing the SSL session, you have to set the SSLIOHandler's `PassThrough` property to False.  It is True by default.

In the `OnConnect` event instead of the `OnOutboundConnect` event, use this:

```
var
  Conn: TIdTCPConnection;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  Conn := TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).OutboundClient;
  SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Conn);
  SSL.PassThrough := False;
  Conn.IOHandler := SSL;
end;
```

Comment: As usual your the man! Thanks for the clarification. I guess the "outbound" thing confused me. I don't think I need to "Free" any resources as it will be freed automatically.

Comment: @MakeG: in a tunnel scenerio, you have an inbound client connecting to `TIdMappedPortTCP` (`AContext`) , and an outbound client connecting to the mapped target server (`AContext.OutboundClient`). And you are correct about object lifetime, since everything is owned by `TIdMappedPortTCP`, except for the SSLIOHandler, which is owned by the `OutboundClient`.